# Submitting Cypher to neo4j through browser

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, neo4j

I'm attempting a hack because I can't find a better way (A native less hacky solution would be much appreciated too)

I'm using neo4j to analyse some graphs. I generate cypher queries and can use py2neo or similar to run them and get back and result. Sometimes I need to show the result and I've used vis.js and toyed with others, but I find the best solution is the one build into the browser on port 7474. I can't find a stand alone I of that js package I could use to display plots in a notebook or website (an answer for this would be great) so I'm using selenium to send the generated queries (the hack)

The submission field for queries is a `div` with a `ReactCodeMirror`  class and a text area. I can't work out how to submit a query to it, as it goes out of focus upon calling `send_keys`

Similar question (but no answer): [How can I execute a cypher query (from java) to neo4j's browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409187/how-can-i-execute-a-cypher-query-from-java-to-neo4js-browser?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the Javascript version of the [Neo4j Movies Example Application](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-javascript-bolt). It shows how to write a web app that dynamically displays query results.

[This article on the example](https://neo4j.com/developer/example-project/#_existing_language_driver_examples) should also be informative.

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial is good but they use a different visualisation library to the browser. I think the browser runs neo4j Bloom which is a separate product, but with as with all Neo4j products they make it impossible to find out how much they cost or how one would actually get it.